# UIImagePickerController only working once

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using UIImagePickerController for users to select the background in my Cocos2D game. It works the first time you use it, but if you try to change the background again the picker will show up, but when you select the image the background will stay the same.

This is my code:

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSArray *TouchesA = touches.allObjects;

    for (int i = 0; i < TouchesA.count; i++) {


        CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:[TouchesA objectAtIndex:i]];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y, 1, 1);

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, infoButton.boundingBox))
        {
            [self pickPhoto:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        }
    }
}

-(void)pickPhoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    //picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    //[picker presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];



    CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];

    Background = imageFromPicker;

    int SSw = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width;
    int SSh = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height;

    Background.position = ccp(SSw/2, SSh/2);

    Background.scaleX = SSw / Background.textureRect.size.width;
    Background.scaleY = SSh / Background.textureRect.size.height;

    [[self children] removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
    [[self children] insertObject:Background atIndex:0];


}
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 

UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    CCSprite *infoButton;
    CCSprite *Background;
    UIImage *newImage;
}



-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        self.isTouchEnabled = true;
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];


        int SSw = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width;
        int SSh = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height;

        Background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"B.jpg"];    

        Background.position = ccp(SSw/2, SSh/2);

        Background.scaleX = SSw / Background.textureRect.size.width;
        Background.scaleY = SSh / Background.textureRect.size.height;



        infoButton = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"info.png"];
        infoButton.position = ccp(SSw - 15, 15);

        [self addChild:Background];
        [self addChild:infoButton];

        [self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem

Check this line:

```
CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
```

and try to replace it with:

```
// resize image
UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// add current shot
CCTexture2D *texture2D = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease]; // this is new
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture2D]; // this is new
```

also look here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/30259?replies=8#post-149117

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like:

```
[Background removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];

Background = imageFromPicker;

int SSw = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.width;
int SSh = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize.height;

Background.position = ccp(SSw/2, SSh/2);

Background.scaleX = SSw / Background.textureRect.size.width;
Background.scaleY = SSh / Background.textureRect.size.height;

[[self children] insertObject:Background atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Sorry about that.. Could you edit your question above with how you instantiate and use `Background`? I made some guesses as to how you do so, which is probably the cause of the crash (for example, maybe you don't `retain` `Background` when you first use it). Thanks!

Comment: There. The top of the edit is from the header of my layer, and the init method is from the .m of my layer.

Comment: It still crashes. ("Up" in removeFromParentAndCleanup isn't supposed to be capatalized. I fixed that and it still crashed.)

Comment: Hey Alex. I'm sorry, but that's about all I can help with.. it's too much of a blackbox to effectively help further. I'd be happy to help more if you could post some of the error messages you're getting. And thanks for the heads up on "Up" not being capitalized -- I've changed my code to reflect that.

Comment: UPDATE: I found that my original function does execute all the way through without errors. It does set the background properly, but it sticks to the image that was chosen first. What could cause this?